# Structure sheaf of the spectrum of the integers

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, affine-schemes

I am learning about schemes and my level is still very basic. Currently, I would, as an exercise, like to solve the following problem:

Let $X = Spec(\mathbb{Z})$: Describe the structure sheaf $\mathcal{O}_X$ of $X$ by exhibiting all restriction morphisms. Do the same for $X = Spec(\mathbb{C}[t]/(t^2-t))$ and $X = Spec(\mathbb{C}[t]/(t^3-t^2))$.

I guess these are very basic and rather simple examples but I have a lot of questions, especially about how to tackle such problems.

Here is what I am aware of: 
Let $A$ be a ring. For $U\subset X$ open $\mathcal{O}_X(U)$ is the projective limit of all $A_f$ s.t. $D(f)\subset U$, where $D(f)$ is the set of all $x\in X$ s.t. $f\notin p_x$ (or $f(x)\neq 0$). The restriction morphisms $\rho^V_U:\mathcal{O}_X(V)\rightarrow \mathcal{O}_X(U)$ are induced by the universal property of the projective limit, since the limits come with maps $\mathcal{O}_X(U)\rightarrow A_f$ and $\mathcal{O}_X(V)\rightarrow A_f$ for $f\in A$ with $D(f)\subset U\subset V$.(right?)

I have read several times that one might identify $\mathcal{O}_X(U)$ with regular "functions" on $U$ that locally around $x\in U$ look like $f/g$ with $g(x)\neq0$ but I don't see why.

Now back to the case where $A=\mathbb{Z}$: How do the rings $\mathcal{O}_X(U)$ look like? Or can I ignore the detailed structure of these rings and somehow find the restriction morphisms right away?

I'd be happy about any hint, comment or remark! :)

Comment: For Spec($\mathbb{Z}$) a lot of what you said is overkill. What are the points here? What are open and closed sets? Are there any open sets that aren't $D(f)$ for some $f$? What is the sheaf over one of these? What happens when I do a restriction?

Comment: Ahh I see, thank you. Maybe I was a bit overwhelmed by all the technicalities. $\mathbb{Z}$ is a P.I.D., so its spectrum contains only closed points. Any closed set $V(E)$ for $E\subset \mathbb{Z}$ is equal to $V( (E) )$, where $(E)$ is the ideal generated by $E$ and hence $(E) = (f)$ for some $f \in\mathbb{Z}$. That is, every open set is of the form $D(f)$ and $\mathcal{O}_X(D(f)) = \mathbb{Z}_{(f)}$. The restriction morphisms $ Z_g\rightarrow  Z_f$ are induced by the universal property of localization of $ \mathbb{Z}\rightarrow  \mathbb{Z}_f$. I will try to handle the other rings next.

Comment: I looked at the other two examples: any prime ideal in $A = \mathbb{C}[t]/(t^2-t)$ corresponds to a prime ideal $(f)$ ($\mathbb{C}[t]$ is a PID) such that $(t^2-t)\subset (f)$. By definition of primes we have $(f) = (t)$ or $(f)=(t-1)$. Every open set is basic open and the restriction maps are the canonical maps $A\rightarrow A_f$ for $f=t,t-1$ or the zero morphism.
What confuses me is that I get the exact same result for  $\mathbb{C}[t]/(t^3-t^2)$...

Comment: Yes for the 2nd and 3rd examples, they should look the same as topological spaces (since, as you've observed, the primes containing the two ideals are the same),  but they can be distinguished by their structure sheaves - the $A$'s when you say 'the exact same result' are different, and that's the difference.

Compare this to $Spec(\mathbb{Z}/6)$ vs $Spec(\mathbb{Z}/12)$ or something. It's the same idea.

Comment: Thanks, I get it now. The difference in structure can only be read off by the underlying ring.